# Erro na instalação do SASS no Windows 8

Tags: ruby, sass, windows-8, gem

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
>            Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 >errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed >(https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Na instalação do Web Starter Kit do Google é necessário instalar alguns componentes: Node, Ruby, Sass e Gulp. Entre eles o que não consigo instalar é o SASS.

Answer (score 1):

### Observação: tenha primeiro o Ruby instalado, [baixe aqui.](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/archives)

Para conseguir realizar com sucesso o comando de instalação do SASS siga as instruções abaixo:

1. Pesquisando o PowerShell

   > Na tela inicial do windows 8, digite a palavra ***"Windows PowerShell"*** e clique para executar.
2. Executar modo Administrador

   > Com o PowerShell aberto, clique com o botão direito do mouse no
   >   powershell na barra de tarefas de aplicativos, clique em "**Executar
   >   como administrador**".

   Vai aparecer essa mensagem: *Deseja permitir que o programa a seguir faça alterações neste computador?* Clique "**SIM**"
3. Adicionar confirmação do certificado da URL

   Digite no PowerShell:

   > gem sources -a http://rubygems.org

   Irá aparecer essa mensagem:

   > > https://rubygems.org is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org
   > >     Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]

   Digite "**Y**", sem as aspas, para aceitar.
4. Instalando o SASS por linha de comando

   Digite no PowerShell:

   > gem install sass

   Pronto! :)